# Swift cannot convert value of type which matches generic constraints

Tags: swift, generics, types, swift4

Given the following types

```
protocol AProtocol {}
protocol AnotherProtocol {}
class AClass: AProtocol, AnotherProtocol {}
```

I'm a bit confused why the following throws: "error: cannot convert value of type 'AClass' to specified type 'T'"

```
class generic<T> where T:AProtocol, T:AnotherProtocol {
    let prop: T = AClass()
}
```

But the following works fine:

```
class generic<T> where T: AProtocol, T: AnotherProtocol {
    let prop: T
    init(withProp prop: T) { self.prop = prop }
}

let instance = generic<AClass>(withProp: AClass())
```

Comment: Because if you had some `BClass` that also implemented `AProtocol & AnotherProtocol` then `T` might be `BClass`, not `AClass`. You can't assume a specific class for T unless you specify that specific class in the constraints

Comment: In other words, it is not possible to refer to an implementation of the generic type(s) from inside the implementation of the generic class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic parameters of your class are specified by the *users* of your class, not *you*.

You can't say that `T` has to be `AClass` like you did in your first code snippet that did not compile, because `T` is specified by the user. A user of your class might want something like:

```
let myObject = generic<BClass>()
```

where `BClass` *also* satisfies the constraints. Then what happens when the user tries to access the property? He will get an instance of `AClass` but `T` is actually `BClass`, so he should really be getting a `BClass`. See the contradiction here?

Regarding your comment:

> In other words, it is not possible to refer to an implementation of the generic type(s) from inside the implementation of the generic class?

Exactly, because you don't know what those types are going to be. You can call methods declared in `AProtocol` and `AnotherProtocol` though. The generic constraints ensure that those methods exist.

If you want to make it work the way you want, you need what's called *protocol composition*:

```
var someProperty: (AProtocol & AnotherProtocol) = AClass()
```

Comment: Ah! Lightbulb moment, yep the contradiction is clear as day. Thanks!